# Is it possible to hide an error message generated by VBS script?

Tags: windows, error-handling, vbscript

I have a customisation on an application that opens the comport to start reading data from the GPS.  Now that I am using a Bluetooth GPS receiver the port doesn't always open the first time.  If it fails it give the message "Error 121 when attempting to open communications port COM(comport number):"

Now when it does this I can check to see if the command worked, and if it didn't fire it again... (see code for the button below)  However it displays an error.

This mimics what happens when you do it manually...  sometimes it takes the Bluetooth stack multiple tries to connect to the GPS...  It doesn't display an error though...

Anyway, it works, but it would be great to not show the error message on the times where the comport doesn't open...

Any and all suggestions are welcome, and appreciated.

Notes:

-The program is working without problems on everything but new units which have to use the Microsoft Bluetooth stack.

-While this error is annoying, the system is otherwise working, and when the Bluetooth connection is made after 1-3 attempts, all is well...

-Before I added "On Error Resume Next" the process would stop whenever the connection didn't get made.

```
Sub subGPSOnOffButton
    'turns the GPS and tracklog on (or off) from a custom button...
    'if the gps is on, make sure the user  wants it off...
    'if the gps is off, turn it on, and tell the user when done.
    Dim iRes
    If Application.GPS.IsOpen = True Then
        iRes = msgbox("GPS is already on!" & vbnewline & vbnewline & "Turn it off?", vbYesNo, "GPS Active:")
        If iRes = 6 then
            Application.GPS.Close()         
        Else 
            Exit Sub
        End if
    Else
        subGPSOn
        msgbox "GPS is now on!", vbOKOnly, "GPS Active:"
    End If
End Sub
Sub subGPSOn
    On Error Resume Next
    Do While Application.GPS.IsOpen = False
        ' Turn the GPS on
        Application.GPS.Open()                                          
    Loop
    ' Turn the tracklog on
    Application.ExecuteCommand("gpstracklog")                       
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show what instantiates `Application` as it is not a built in VBScript object?

Comment: Hi Lankymary, its part of the core application that the VBS is read into.